# HTML5: Remembering location setting in Firefox

Tags: firefox, geolocation, firefox4

I have a page with a Google Maps component, and I am using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` on initiating the map so that I can show "local" items.

Everything works great, other than the behavior of the location prompt - In the past I thought I had seen where you could choose to allow FireFox to remember this setting, but that has either been removed from FireFox, or there is some flag/setting that I'm not using that would enable this...  anyone have any insight?

See this page for a screencap of the 'remember' checkbox:

http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html

Thanks,

Paul

EDIT:

Ok, looks like I am only seeing this issue in FireFox 4, in that it doesn't seem to give me the option to remember the site in the prompt, which means it prompts each and every time. FireFox 3.5 works as expected. Is this expected behavior? I can manually set it to never ask by going into Page Info for the page, but the typical user is not going to know how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it appears that version 4.0.1 of FF doesn't have the 'remember permission' checkbox... the user will get prompted each and every time they hit the page until they perform the following steps:

Right-Click->'View Page Info'->'Permissions' Tab->'Share Location' and then un-check 'Always ask' set the radio button to 'allow'.

Seems like most people would never know to look there for this setting though, hopefully they re-introduce the dialog 'remember' checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you did already gave permission, Firefox will not ask again. You may undo it according http://www.mozilla.com/en/firefox/geolocation/

Comment: No, I am getting prompted every time the page loads - I'd like to do just what you are saying and 'save/remember' the share location setting for the page.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem (FF 8.01 on Win7), I can confirm Firefox keeps asking for location permission, even when explicitly stating a cache age in getCurrentPosition.